# About constructor call for base and derived class

Tags: c++, oop

I am new in C++ and I have just started studying polymorphism. I know that if I create an object for the derived class then the constructor of both derived and base class is get called. Does it mean that, when I create an object for the derived class, eventually I am ending up with two objects- one is created by the constructor of base class and another one created by the constructor of derived class?

Can anyone explain, what is the job of base class constructor when I want to create an object for the derived class.

Answer (score 10):

The job of the base class constructor is to initialise the base class member variables (consider the case of a `private` member variable in the base class).

When you call a constructor for a derived object, you only end up with one object. The base class constructor initialises the base class parts of the new object, and the derived constructor initialises the derived class parts of the same new object.

Answer (score 2):

Constructors do not allocate space and initiate instances of objects; they initialise the object immediately after space has been allocated.

When you declare a object on the stack or use *new* first the memory is reserved and object is created, then the constructors are executed, starting with the base constructor and working upwards towards the most derived class.

Comment: As an object's lifetime doesn't begin until its constructor completes I would say that constructors _do_ create objects (in the allocated memory area for which they are called). C++ isn't like Java where the constructors are more like post-creation initialization functions (e.g. you can call `super` from a constructor body in Java).

Comment: @Charles Have edited my answer to change the vocabulary slightly so as not to imply they are java-like.

Answer (score 1):

You will end up with a derived class object, that contains a base class object.

Constructors don't magically create another instance of an object.  They initialise a certain piece of memory, but calling a constructor and allocating memory are not the same thing -- the latter is either done behind the scenes (for objects with automatic and static storage duration) or with `new` and `malloc` (for objects with dynamic storage duration).

EDIT:  Before I get angry comments about it: "behind the scenes" is a vague way to put it; the definition of an object with automatic or static storage duration ensures that it gets memory.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you are creating an `object` of the `base class` or `derived class`, you end up with one object.

Just because the base class constructor is called, it doesn't mean you get one extra object for that call. Here, the b`ase class constructor` will be executed, which typically sets attributes of the base class. The object on the whole would be composed of the base class properties and derived class properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class then you would have to define a contructor or constructors (there are certain circumstances in where you do not have to). A constructor has the purpose to initialise the class data members, you give a value to its data members. Any data member that you do not give it a value, will have an undefined value unless the data member is an instance of a class that happens to have a default constructor.

So when you create an instance of that class, the compiler will invoke the appropriate constructor, and the members of the instance that you have just created will have data initialised with values as you set them in the constructor.

If you have a derived class, you can add data members to it, but remember that it has also an inherited member: the base class. So when you define a constructor in you derived class, you must invoke a constructor of the base class (so that the members of the base class get fully initialised) and assign value to the derived class own data members.

So you create an instance of the derived class, the derived class constructor is invoved. As part of its functionality it invokes the constructor of its base class (so you might say two constructors but this is the wrong of viewing it).

If you create an instance of the base class, only that constructor is invoked.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So, in sum, if I create an object for the derived class then first, the base class constructor will be called to initialize the base class members, then the derived class constructor will be called and it will create the new derived class object. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When we create an object, Constructor will be called. Its not when constructor called object is being created.

You can assume Creating object as a function and Constructor is another function which is called inside it.

Assume A is a base class and B is a derived class,

class A
{

}

class B : public A
{

}

We will be creating object for class A in below ways,

```
A obja;

or 

A obja = new A();
```

In both cases you can assume a function Create is getting called,

```
A::Create()
{
   A();
}
```

If you are creating Derived class B object then Create method of B will be called,

So internally Create method of B will look like below,

```
B::Create()
{
  B();
  A();
}
```

So when we create Derived class object first derived class initialization happens and then Base class initialization happen. It not means object is created twice.

Object will be created for the Call where you are creating object using.

B obj;

or

B obj = new B();

Calling the constructors are internal functionality as Constructors called in the Create function.

Note : `Create` function in the above code is done only for illustrative purpose.

Comment: -1 I believe substituting Create for the constructor call confuses much more than it illustrates the issues here. Especially in that one has to explicitly call base overridden function (refinement) but NOT constructors.

Answer (score 0):

when object of a derived class is created then constructor function of that class will be created first then to use the constructor function of the base class will be called by a separate object at the time of calling it will be invoked by that object.