# Sizeof of subclass not always equals to sum of sizeof of superclass. So what is with non used memory?

Tags: c++, memory-management

The code that I've written:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct S
{
    long l;
};

struct A
{
    int a;
};

struct B : A, S{ };

int main()
{
    cout << "sizeof(A) = " << sizeof(A) << endl; //4
    cout << "sizeof(S) = " << sizeof(S) << endl; //8
    cout << "sizeof(B) = " << sizeof(B) << endl; //16 != 4 + 8
}
```

[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf9382731f936357)

Why do we have to allocate an additional 4 bytes for `B`? How this additional memory is used?

Comment: Related: [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member/119128#119128). Some of the answers are very well-formed.

Comment: @WhozCraig Not sure if it's 'related'. Seems like a duplicate.

Comment: @Rapptz it really isn't. Stacking in class derivation is one thing *not* particularly covered in those answers. The ideas of layout, alignment, and padding, are nicely covered, however.

Comment: possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813756/inheritance-and-size-of-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Memory image of a `B` instance:**

```
int  a; // bytes 0-3
long l; // bytes 4-11
```

**Problem:**

`l` is an 8-byte variable, but its address is not aligned to 8 bytes. As a result, unless the underlying HW architecture supports unaligned load/store operations, the compiler cannot generate correct assembly code.

**Solution:**

The compiler adds a 4-byte padding after variable `a`, in order to align variable `l` to an 8-byte address.

**Memory image of a `B` instance:**

```
int  a; // bytes 0-3
int  p; // bytes 4-7
long l; // bytes 8-15
```

Comment: Problem? There's no problem here.

Comment: The compiler has no trouble generating correct assembly code. It inserts padding into the structs on its own, you don't need to do it manually. The OP's question is a demonstration of this.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Who said you need to do it manually??? The answer explains how the compiler solves this problem!!!

Comment: Well, it doesn't sound like that's what you're saying. You say, "the compiler cannot generate correct assembly code", then you provide a solution which sounds like an instruction to the reader, not an explanation of what the compiler does.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: I think that since the question doesn't refer to any runtime error, it's pretty obvious that the answer explains how a given problem is solved (rather than stating that there is a problem in generating compiled code). The model of the answer - Description, Problem, Solution, Description - is simply there to depict the situation.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Nevertheless, using the word "Add" might have been slightly misleading here, so I changed it to "The compiler adds"...

Comment: You answer seems logical for me. Accepted.

Answer (score 0):

For POD data type, there can be padding and alignments.

Answer (score 0):

In B's memory layout, `int` comes first, then `long`. The compiler likely inserts 4 bytes of padding between them to 8-align the long assuming any instance of the structure will also have its starting address 8-aligned.

Similar things would happen if you put an `A` and a `S` instance on your stack: the compiler would leave 4 bytes empty in between.

See [Data Structure Alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment).

Comment: The order between `long` and `int` doesn't matter; even if the `long` is first you still need to add padding to make the overall structure align properly.

Comment: Yes, but this is not reflected in the size of the structure.

Comment: It is - `struct A { long l; }; struct B { int i; }; struct C : A, B {};`, then `sizeof(C)` is 16 (assuming 8-byte `long` and 4-byte `int`).

Comment: You're right - otherwise it wouldn't work with i.e. continuous arrays of `C`.